# Center a Button Vertically in a Table in the CSS Foundation Framework?

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

I have a Foundation button:

```
<a href="#" class="button tiny alert radius FormSubmit">Delete</a>
```

Which is inside a table row cell: ``button```

[image]

As you can see the button is not aligned vertically centered.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fqk8ossu/2/) I created to show the problem.

```
<table class="centered columns">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Granted</td>
            <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>true</td>
            <td><a href="#" class="button tiny alert radius FormSubmit">Delete</a>  </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

**How can I center a Button Vertically in a Table in the CSS Foundation Framework?**

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle of the problem?

Comment: It's hard to play with a screenshot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to align text vertically center in div with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css)

Comment: I updated my answer here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fqk8ossu/2/

Comment: Take a look at the Related section in the sidebar. There's probably no Foundation mechanism for this, but it's been asked and answered many times otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are just need to remove the button `margin-bottom` property.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fqk8ossu/18/)

Answer (score 1):

This will centre everything in the middle of your table. But as its CSS3 you will need to only be worried about modern browsers.

```
td{
  position:relative; 
}
.button{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fqk8ossu/12/)

Comment: I updated your jsfiddle the `td` needs `position:relative` so the button does not jump up

Answer (score 1):

Just add Margin Auto to button class

```
.button{
    margin: auto;
}
```

and remove previous styling Because it will sift up and it will not work;Auto will also be responsive as compare to position absolute

Answer (score 0):

add id="top-padding" into button and add this bit of CSS

```
<style>
#top-padding {
padding-top: 10px;

}

</style>
```

might not be perfect but you can mess around with the number of pixels until it is centered

Comment: Ha ha this is a dirty fix and not very elegant.

Comment: haha better dirty than not working. At least a short-term solution